# Why is permutation used in the knn classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, classification

I am new to ML and I don't understand why a random permutation is used for KNN. I am referring to http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scikit-learn/ in the k-Nearest neighbors classifier section. The following code was provided:

```
>>> perm = np.random.permutation(iris.target.size)
>>> iris.data = iris.data[perm]
>>> iris.target = iris.target[perm]
>>> knn.fit(iris.data[:100], iris.target[:100]) 
KNeighborsClassifier(...)
>>> knn.score(iris.data[100:], iris.target[100:]) 
0.95999...
```

And this question was asked: `Bonus question: why did we use a random permutation?`

Can someone help explain why a permutation would affect the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iris is by default sorted, first 50 instances form class 1, next class 2, and last class 3. So they would train solely on class 1 and 2 and try to predict labels of class 3 if they do not permute. In general it is a good practise to start from permuting data, as they can always be some kind of structure involved due to the approach taken by the dataset creator.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your dataset has sorting or groupings that you are not aware of. Usually you separate your model in training, test, and validation. At first glance in knn that is not explicitly required, because the algorithm in purely online. Let's see how it works,

A1. A data set is given.

A2. A candidate point is given

A3. The candidate point is classified with a majority voting of the k nearest neighbor classes.

However that is the case when the data set encompasses all the required knowledge, i.e. It is the ground truth.

In case that the dataset is not as such that we randomize and separate in training and validation, then we classify against train and check against validation to see if the training was successful. This is an iterative process of randomization and test until we get a train set that nicely evaluates on the validation set. Once this process is finished the test set is used to evaluate the generalization ability of the process.

Comment: just a note - you confuse names "validation" and "test", test set is used for checking the final generalization capabilities, not validation. Furthermore, the OP question (and the related link) has nothing to do with estimating expected values over the space of training set - which you are refering to, the OP actual problem is completely (and correctly) addressed in the very first sentence of your answer.